# Can anyone help me in redirect based on age?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

There have a age picker.

If 18-31 y/old >Button > link to a website.......

Otherwish 32-99 y/old > same button >link to another another

Probable code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Add your Age</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">

  
  <script>
  $( function() {
       $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth:true,
        changeYear:true,
        yearRange:"1920:2021"

       });
        $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');

  } );

  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<button style="background: orange; border: none;padding: 10px 25px;margin-left:40px;">Ok</button>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy";
  var age = 0;
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "1920:2021",
    onSelect: function(dateText, uiObject) {
      var now = new Date();
      var birth = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", dateText);
      age = now.getFullYear() - birth.getFullYear();
    }
  });
  $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
  $("button").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (age > 17 && age < 32) {
      console.log("Age 1:", age);
      // Redirect to Page 1
    }
    if (age > 31) {
      console.log("Age 2:", age);
      // Redirect to Page 2
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Birth Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<button class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-priority-primary">Ok</button>
```

This sets a `age` variable based on the Users selection. You can then conditionally Redirect based on the `age`.

See more:

- https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect
- https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/ view Utility Functions

Comment: its work out,thanks bro

Comment: @dipubarman thats good to hear. You can Mark it as the answer by clicking the checkmark. Later, if you choose, you can upvote the answer too.

Comment: this file is index.html,how can i add the location of index2.html at the (Redirect to Page 2) code and redirect this page.

Comment: @dipubarman your questions was in regards to how to perform an action based on a specific selected Date. I have addressed that question. I would advise something like `window.location.href=""` or you can try it yourself. If you need more help, search for similar posts or post a new question.

Comment: I did it Dear. Thank you Very much Again

Comment: Brother if i want to this make https://snipboard.io/DPcVtF.jpg design, what will be possible change in the code?

Comment: The screenshot: http://prnt.sc/22atrv2

Comment: @dipubarman you would have to write all new code.

Comment: yes i mada a code,I am giving you the new code@Twisty

Comment: please check this code https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iqCo2CuvPP5Sm_olIZFoovXBlsiG0H6o/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @dipubarman you will want to work on the code and if you get to a point where you are stuck, you may want to investigate the issue or post another question. What you are asking goes well beyond the scope of this question you asked originally.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var link = document.getElementById('link');
var age = document.getElementById('ageInput');
var selectedAge;

age.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.value === '18-31') {
    link.text = 'Foo';
    link.href = '/foo';
  } else {
    link.text = 'Bar';
    link.href = '/bar';
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label>
Select age:
<select id="ageInput">
  <option value="18-31">18-31</option>
  <option value="32-99">32-99</option>
</select>

<a id="link" href=""></a>
```

Comment: Thanks,its work out.but i need a little bit difference.please check the code thats i add.